# Immediately update .NET EF database after bound WPF control change

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have created a .NET project that uses the Entity Framework and WPF for the UI. The UI contains a DataGrid with two columns, one ordinary read-only `DataGridTextColumn` and one `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `Checkbox` inside to enable single-click editing:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedForDisplay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FullName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have checked that the binding of the checkbox works by changing some entries in the database directly. Now I would like the application to immediately commit changes to the selection checkbox to the underlying database. How could I do this? Adding some event handler to the view logic feels wrong, but I'm not sure what alternatives I have.

Comment: I don't know more but you should use UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged for IsChecked Property.

Comment: I don't recon it is possible to automatically update database . Either you have to use 'checked' event and call database update or use a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and handle update from a button click.

Answer (score 0):

If the class that has the `IsSelectedForDisplay` property implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then you can attach a handler to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event of each data item in the collection. When a property is changed, you'll be notified and then you can save the change. You could do something like this:

```
item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
```

...

```
private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as YourClass) != null) 
    {
        SaveDataType((YourClass)sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I would have to listen to the data source as well and register to all newly created objects in the collection - quite a lot of manual logic.

Comment: *quite a lot of manual logic*... nonsense. Create a class that extends the `ObservableCollection<T>` class and then you can easily attach a handler to each item in the constructor and `Add` and `Insert` methods. I use this method myself.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging based on the hint to use `UpdateSourceTrigger`, I found the following solution:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedForDisplay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Binding.SourceUpdated="Binding_SourceUpdated" />
```

In the event handler, I can call `dbContext.SaveChanges();` (although I will probably replace this by an event to decouple the view from the remaining logic later on.)